# How can i deploy tensorflow with pyinstaller or cx_freeze or py2exe

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller

Im trying to build a tensorflow based app, my first try was in pyinstaller but the .exe file is huge (934 Mb) excluding the model, ill put in the code, its just a loader of a keras model,

```
print("Cargando tensorflow")
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
print("Cargando numpy")
from numpy import array
print("Cargando cv2")
from cv2 import imread
print("Cargando os")
print("Cargando tkinter")
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
print("holaaa")
try:
    filename = askopenfilename(initialdir="./",title='Cargar modelo',filetypes=[("Modelos de Keras", "*.keras")])
    modelo1 = load_model(filename)
    print("Modelos cargados")
except Exception as e:
    print("hubo un error")
    with open('log.txt','w+') as thefile:
        thefile.write(e)
        print('ver el log')
    modelo1 = load_model('ModeloT1.keras')
    print('usando el modelo local')

state = 1
while 1:
    filename = askopenfilename(initialdir="./",title='hola')
    state = 1
    print(filename)

    try:
        img = imread(filename)
        norm_img = img/255
        new_img = array([norm_img])
    except Exception as e:
        respuesta = input('No se ha detectado ninguna imagen,Desea salir (Y/N)')
        if respuesta.lower() == 'y':
            quit()
        elif respuesta.lower() == 'n':
            state = 0
            pass
        else:
            print("No se ha proporcionado una respuesta clara")
            
    if state:
        prediccion1 = modelo1.predict(new_img)
        if prediccion1[0] < 0.5:
            titulo = 'Ricardo '
        else:
            titulo ='Yuly'
        print(titulo)
```

please ignore the spanish sentences

the .spec file is the following

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['TestField.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['tensorflow.keras.models', 'cv2', 'tkinter.filedialog'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=['scipy','tensorboard','google','h5py','tensorflow.dtensor','tensorflow.distribute','tensorflow.compiler','tensorflow_datasets','tensorflow_io','tensorflowjs','tfjs_graph_converter','PyQt5','PyQt6','matplotlib','astor','iPython','distutils','multiprocessing','pickle','setuptools','sqlite3','jedi','lib2to3','certifi'],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=True,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='TestField',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=True,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

the spec file give me .exe with 407Mb but its to much bro, any advice?

i was expecting a .exe with 200Mb at least